# Combine fields of multiple tables returns too many rows when more than 1 field is used

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have the following query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT x.TaskID S_ID
              , y.TaskID T_ID
              , z.TaskID P_ID
              , z.Duration
           FROM SumSubTaskPDay x
           LEFT 
           JOIN SumTaskPDay y 
             ON y.TaskID = x.T_ID
           LEFT 
           JOIN SumParentTaskPDay z
             ON z.TaskID = SumTaskPDay.y
```

The issue I'm having is that the query returns too many rows as soon as I add another field besides the ID's.

So in this example, the field `SumParentTaskPDay`.`Duration` causes the row count to quadruple more or less

The issue is probably in the tables who are actually views from 3 aliases from the same table `tasks`:
`tasks` as `subtasks` is linked to `tasks` as `tasks` with `tasks`.`id` = `subtasks`.`parent_id`

```
  CREATE  VIEW SumTaskPDay AS
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(n.START, '%d %M %Y') dDay
     , t.idTask TaskID
     , t.TaskName 
     , t.ParentTaskId PT_ID
     , COUNT(s.idTask) SubTaskCount
     , SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(n.STOP) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(n.START)) DurationUnix
     , DATE_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(n.STOP) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(n.START))), '%H:%i:%s') Duration
  FROM Slips n
  LEFT 
  JOIN Tasks s 
    ON s.idTask = n.idTask
  LEFT 
  JOIN Tasks t 
    ON t.idTask = s.ParentTaskId
 GROUP 
    BY dDay 
     , t.idTask 
     , t.TaskName 
     , t.ParentTaskId
```

I use this approach to sum up the duration fields for the different levels, so I can fetch a simple view for building a report, where I only have to care about grouping, no formulas and stuff, so I can easily switch to different report building tools without hours of figuring out the way to sum and format timestamps

Comment: I would disourage the use of views in MySQL. They serve very little useful purpose, and have only a limited ability to use indexes efficiently. In consequence, they're often slower than they're 'plain query' equivalents.

Comment: First of all, thanks for cleaning up this code and showing me a proper way to keep code readable. 
Can you post a link with more information on views (and the better alternative) ?